# Help me identify this type of pin header

Tags: identification, pins, header

Can you help me identify this type of pin header?

[image]
[image]

I know it's a SIP (single in line) package, but would this type of connector be male or female since it has both gender types of connectors?

Also, could anyone suggest a distributor to purchase this type of header in bulk?

Comment: Purchasing recommendations are off-topic, but you can get them from pretty much anywhere.

Comment: The short pins are soldered to a PCB. Therefore only leaving the female side available. The connector is female. I'm too lazy to find them on Digikey, but here they are on Sparkfun: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/115

Comment: 2 S7035-ND S5477-ND
3 S7036-ND S5478-ND
4 S7037-ND S5479-ND
5 S7038-ND S5480-ND
6 S7039-ND S5481-ND
8 S7041-ND S5483-ND

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a female pin header, most likely 0.1"/100mil/2.54mm (but use your calipers to verify). The little metal pins are for soldering into a PCB, whereas the corresponding male connector plugs into the contacts embedded within the plastic housing.

Also note that they are available in "stackable" form, where the metal pins are long enough for the connector to act as both male and female; these are used on both PC/104 expansion boards and Arduino shields so that they can be stacked multiple devices high.